# \multido does not do anything

Tags: pstricks, multido

The example below was downloaded from that site with pstricks examples. When I run it I get 18 blank pages. This also happens with other examples using multido. I'm using texmaker with MikTex 2.9. Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\colorlet{Green}{green!100!white!40}
\begin{document}

\multido{\iA=0+15}{18}{%
\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=30 \iA\space 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=25}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-2)(5,2)
\psSolid[object=grille,grid,
 fcol= /t 0 def 0 1 63 { dup dup 8 mod 0 eq { /t t 1 add def } if 
     t add 2 mod 0 eq { (Green) }{ (red) } ifelse } for, 
base=-4 4 -4 4]
\end{pspicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `standalone` is cropping an incorrect location on the page. If you just use `article` and add `\newpage` as the first element *inside* `\multido`, you'll see the 18 rotations of a chessboard.

Comment: `... that site with pstricks examples`. I hope people take as much care to attribute your ideas, work and creations to you as you do to acknowledge theirs.  It is also of absolutely no use to anybody who wants to follow up by finding the original or seeing what else is available at the mentioned site. Depending on the licence, it may be illegal to post the content here in this way. But whether it is legal or no, it is extremely rude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence with TeXLive 2015 and did not find any problem using either `standalone` or `article` or `article` with `preview`.

## `standalone`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\colorlet{Green}{green!100!white!40}
\begin{document}

\multido{\iA=0+15}{18}{%
\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=30 \iA\space 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=25}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-2)(5,2)
\psSolid[object=grille,grid,
 fcol= /t 0 def 0 1 63 { dup dup 8 mod 0 eq { /t t 1 add def } if 
     t add 2 mod 0 eq { (Green) }{ (red) } ifelse } for, 
base=-4 4 -4 4]
\end{pspicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

## `article` alone

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}


\colorlet{Green}{green!100!white!40}
\begin{document}

\multido{\iA=0+15}{18}{%
\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=30 \iA\space 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=25}%
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-2)(5,2)
\psSolid[object=grille,grid,
 fcol= /t 0 def 0 1 63 { dup dup 8 mod 0 eq { /t t 1 add def } if 
     t add 2 mod 0 eq { (Green) }{ (red) } ifelse } for, 
base=-4 4 -4 4]
\end{pspicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

## `article` with `preview`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\colorlet{Green}{green!100!white!40}
\begin{document}

\multido{\iA=0+15}{18}{%
\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=30 \iA\space 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=25}%
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-2)(5,2)
\psSolid[object=grille,grid,
 fcol= /t 0 def 0 1 63 { dup dup 8 mod 0 eq { /t t 1 add def } if 
     t add 2 mod 0 eq { (Green) }{ (red) } ifelse } for, 
base=-4 4 -4 4]
\end{pspicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit

I just installed TeX Live 2016 and here I confirmed that the `standalone` version above produces a PDF of 18 blank pages. This problem can be fixed by inserting `preview` option as Herbert's answer.

Answer (score 2):

[`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) is cropping an incorrect location on the page when only using `pstricks` as the class option under `latex` > `dvips` > `ps2pdf`. Rather compile with `xelatex` or add the `preview` option to the class:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\colorlet{Green}{green!100!white!40}
\pagestyle{empty}% Remove header/footer
\begin{document}

\multido{\iA=0+15}{18}{%
  \newpage% One page per image
  \psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=30 \iA\space 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=25}
  \begin{pspicture}(-5,-2)(5,2)
    \psSolid[object=grille,grid,
            fcol= /t 0 def 0 1 63 { dup dup 8 mod 0 eq { /t t 1 add def } if 
              t add 2 mod 0 eq { (Green) }{ (red) } ifelse } for, 
            base=-4 4 -4 4]
  \end{pspicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

If you just use `article` and add `\newpage` as the first element *inside* `\multido`, you'll see the 18 rotations of a chessboard.

Comment: `standalone` has _no_ problems to crop the image!

Comment: @Herbert: I couldn't get it to show the correct crop under TeX Live 2016 with a LaTeX > dvips > ps2pdf sequence. The output remains to be 18 blank pages. [Here is my file list](http://pastebin.com/azpXx3GS) when compiling the OP. `article` with [`preview`](http://ctan.org/pkg/preview) worked. Are you running TeX Live 2015? Could you share your file list?

Comment: do you have `\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}` ? If yes, then there is a problem with TL2015. In TL2016 everything is fine.

Comment: @Herbert: Yes, I have `\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}` just like in the original post under TeX Live 2016: pdfTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX) (preloaded format=latex 2016.8.2); dvips(k) 5.996; kpathsea version 6.2.2; tested on Ghostscript versions 9.10, 9.14, 9.19 and 9.20 (all 64 bit).

Comment: and what happens when running `xelatex`?

Comment: @Herbert: `xelatex` runs smoothly with a cropped output.

Comment: ok, then use `\documentclass[pstricks,crop=false]{standalone}` and it should work with `dvips`

Comment: @Herbert: This produces a single page that has the chess boards running off the page. The idea behind using `standalone` would be to have a single cropped page per image. Don't you think it's a problem with `standalone` under `latex` > `dvips` > `ps2pdf`?

Comment: the single page is the default behaviour. With `\documentclass[pstricks,preview]{standalone}` you'll get the single pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview]{standalone}
```

and you'll get the single pages with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why `preview` option is now needed in TeX Live 2016 but not in the previous version.

Comment: `standalone` changes ...