# TeXLive 2016: Standalone + pstricks not working

Tags: pstricks, texlive, standalone, texlive-2016

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,4)
\psline(0,0)(5,4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I can use both, TeXLive 2015 and TeXLive 2016, to successfully compile the code. However, the result of the usual latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf chain is an empty picture in the 2016 (up-to-date) case. The 2015 version of latex works just fine:

2015 PDF:

[image]

2016 PDF:

[image]

I'd like to file a bug report, any recommendation where to further look into and where to actually put the bug report?

My question is different to [\multido does not do anything](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331174/multido-does-not-do-anything) as it is much more centered on the actual problem (includes an **M**WE) and, as such, is much more likely to be found by users encountering the same problem in the future.

Comment: that's odd, it works with 2016 xelatex

Comment: with latex-dvips the line is still in the postscript but is dropped in ps2pdf...

Comment: That is weird, I use the very same dvips and ps2pdf in both cases.

Comment: @David If I enlarge the picture and the line to something more or less A4 ((20,28)), then the line appears, so I would say ps2pdf is cutting the wrong piece.  Imho the problem is the "setpagesize" code  in dvips.def (when I use the new dvips.def with tl15 the line disappears there too).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes the bb and setpagedevice setting seem odd, I got same with tl2015, but perhaps your comment implies it was an update during the tl2015 cycle?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If I remember correctly dvips handles such settings in an odd way and the first settings wins -- which is difficult for standalone.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: see https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/25/pagesize-special-clipping. `\RequirePackage[nosetpagesize]{graphics}` before \documentclass works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was wondering if I'd broken it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the option  `preview`  as follows and you will get the expected result.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,4)
\psline(0,0)(5,4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331174/multido-does-not-do-anything#comment813380_331470

Answer (score 6):

The issue is known and has been reported a the standalone bug tracker:
https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/25/pagesize-special-clipping

Work arounds are:

```
\RequirePackage[nosetpagesize]{graphics}
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,4)
\psline(0,0)(5,4)
\end{pspicture}


\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,5)
\psline(0,0)(3,5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\def\sa@papersize{%
    \global\let\sa@papersize\relax
    \global\sa@yoffset=\paperheight
\global \setbox \@begindvibox
    \vbox{%
    \special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}%
    \special{ps::%
        \@percentchar\@percentchar HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 \the\paperwidth\space\the\paperheight^^J%
    }%
\unvbox \@begindvibox }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,4)
\psline(0,0)(5,4)
\end{pspicture}


\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,5)
\psline(0,0)(3,5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the new dvips in TL 2017, no workaround will be needed.
The last `\special{papersize=w,h}` is effective in the
new dvips, as in the (x)dvipdfmx. A new option `-L0`
recovers the old behavior in which the first
`\special{papersize=w,h}` wins.